# What genre my wife is writing?

Tags: genre

In advance: I'm sorry for write so badly in English. I am a Spanish writer.

My wife is writing a book about the life of 4 women. This morning she asked me about which genre her novel belongs to.

At first, I respond very quickly "literary fiction". But now, after talking about the way she has been orienting the scenes, I'm not so sure.

In general,  she is writing about 4 women of different ages, living through different dramatics situations. The setting is contemporary, and the women are all between 25 and 45 years. Every character shows part of her life and her way to take the best decisions for her family, friends and for themself.

At the end, it is just a picture of the way that women live on our current times and society.

My question: which is this genre?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to the community, Hedufigo.

It sounds to me as though your wife is clearly writing "[Women's Fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Women%27s_fiction)."

> Women's fiction is an umbrella term for women centered books that
>   focus on women's life experience that are marketed to female readers,
>   and includes many mainstream novels. It is distinct from Women's
>   writing, which refers to literature written by (rather than promoted
>   to) women.

**Edit:**

I am not certain why this answer is being down voted.

Three hundred and eighty four literary agents (384) on AgentQuery self-identify as [representing "Women's fiction"](https://www.agentquery.com/search.aspx) and it is clearly defined on many writer blogs, agencies, and so on. Barnes and Noble has [an entire section](https://www.barnesandnoble.com/b/books/fiction/womens-fiction/_/N-29Z8q8Z10mx) for Women's Fiction. [Many authors](https://www.wrl.org/books-and-reading/adults/100-contemporary-american-women-fiction-writers) write Women's Fiction. In fact, there is [a writer's association](https://www.womensfictionwriters.org) specifically for Women's Fiction.

If men want a "Men's Fiction" genre, the way to get it is not to say that "Women's Fiction" does not exist.  That's veering quite close to mysogyny.

You can't simply say that something doesn't exist--when that thing has dedicated writers, agents, associations, awards, and so on and so forth.

This is beyond bizarre to me.

Original poster, your description is very clearly Women's  Fiction,

**And there are 384 agents that represent the sort of book your wife is writing. It is a recognized genre.**

Comment: I deliberately didn't use that term because too often any book written about a female main character gets thrown into that bin.  But we never see "men's fiction" as a label.  Books about male characters are just "fiction."

Comment: Comicbooks are "men's fiction".

Comment: Not the comic books I read.  <g>

Comment: Yes, it's a known grouping. So is "chick flick" for movies. But it's a poor way to divide up literature and has sexist underpinnings, even if you had zero intention to present it that way. I still will not call "Women's fiction" a genre. A marketing term, sure. A category, absolutely. But it's not a primary division I'd want to use, like contemporary vs historical or adult vs young adult. It may be that Hudufigo's wife's novel will get marketed as WF. But that's not the starting classification. And just because it's about women's lives doesn't mean it should be diverted to the WF shelf.

Comment: Cyn.  If women see a need for literature devoted to women's issues, and men do not see such a need for an analogous category, that may be rooted in historical trends rather than whatever point you think you are making.  Consider the analogous situation playing out in the US right now: The supreme court and the GOP of the US are both being led by old white males. They think they know what women need. Do you support that ideology? If you're not a woman, and are trying to wave some bizarre flag of equality, I'm calling BS. It makes no difference if you call it a genre, when 384 agents do.

Comment: DPT, I believe @Cyn's claim wasn't that there's no need for literature devoted to women's issues, but rather that literature devoted to women's issues is part of "literature devoted to people's issues", women being people. Nor should such literature be read exclusively by women - why shouldn't men also read it? Thus, literature about people, for people = fiction.

Comment: @Galastel That makes even less sense to me. Science fiction is fiction. Erotica is romance. Romance is fiction. Every fiction genre is fiction. So we are reduced to two genres. Fiction and nonfiction. But both, conveniently, are books. So we have one genre. "Books." Who has ever said only women can read Women's fiction? The definition of WF is "women centered books that focus on women's life experience that are marketed to female readers, **and includes many mainstream novels.**" "Market to women" in my understanding has to do with historical bias in writing and publishing. Not exclusivity.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like straight-forward contemporary adult fiction.  Good luck to her!

Comment: Agree. "Women" are not a genre. It's just called "fiction".